# Clojure - a let in a macro won't work

Tags: macros, clojure, let

I have created a macro which creates a named `dispatcher` with 3 associates functions `get-dispatcher`, `set-dispatcher` and `call-dispatcher` to work with the dispatcher (they get a dispatching function, add one or call one). It all works just fine! However, now I want to automate the related functions names creation, thus I am putting all these internals of the macro into a `let` which defines that simple construction function. Note that in the code below only the `get-` function's name is constructed with that automation. The `set-` and `call-` ones name creation still has that manual smell.

```
(defmacro create-dispatcher [name]
  ;creates a set of dispatching functions tagged

  `(do
    ;define dispatcher
    (def ~(symbol name) ~(atom {}))

    (let
      [name-w-prefix (fn [x] (~(symbol (str x "-" name))))]
        ; -- define getter
        (defn (name-w-prefix "get")
          "get-dispatcher [tag]: get a dispatcher fn by tag"
          (~'[] (println "no tag is provided for '" ~(str name) "' dispatcher"))
          (~'[tag]
            (do
              (println "dispatcher '" ~(str name) "' called with '" ~'tag "' tag")
              ; return the tagged dispatcher
              ( (keyword ~'tag) @~(symbol name) )))

        )
        ; -- define caller
        (defn ~(symbol (str "call-" name))
          "get-dispatcher [tag & args]: call a dispatcher fn by tag and apply to the args"
          ~'[tag & args]
          (apply (~(symbol (str "get-" name)) ~'tag) ~'args)
          )
        ; -- define setter
        (defn ~(symbol (str "set-" name))
          ~'[tag fn]
          "add-dispatcher [tag fn]: add a dispatcher fn associated with the tag"
          (swap! ~(symbol name) assoc (keyword ~'tag) ~'fn)
          )
     )

    ; -- report
    (println "created dispatcher set for '" ~(str name) "' ok!")
    ))
```

However, there is a problem. The `name-w-prefix` in the `let` statement binding causes errors. How can I fix that?

(also any advices on improvement are welcome since I am a newb and that is almost the first thing that I wrote in Clojure)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All symbols in a macro are resolved in the current namespace and expected to evaluate to a var. You could quote the `name-w-prefix` symbol, but that would risk colliding with symbols passed in to the macro during macro expansion. So, Clojure provides a special syntax for use in syntax-quoted forms for generating symbols - just append a `#` to the end of the symbol and Clojure will treat that as a quoted, auto-generated symbol. So in this case, replace occurrences of `name-w-prefix` with `name-w-prefix#` and you should be good to go.

Taking a step back and looking at what your overall goal is, I think you should move the `name-w-prefix` definition *outside* the syntax quotes and then use syntax-escape to call it. Otherwise, you'll get still more errors because `defn` requires a symbol, so once expanded the macro must produce a `defn` form that has a symbol as its second item. Something along the lines of:

```
(defmacro create-dispatcher [name]
  (let [name-w-prefix #(symbol (str % "-" name))]
    `(do
       (def ~(symbol name) (atom {}))
       (defn ~(name-w-prefix "get")
         ([] (println "no tag provided"))
         ([tag#] (println "called with tag" tag#))))))
```

Note that I've changed `~'[tag]` to `[tag#]` in the `defn` body in accordance with what I was talking about above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Did not know that.. but I did it and now it complains about the `x` symbol in the function definition..

Comment: See edit. I think you're a little bit confused about what goes inside and outside of syntax quotes.

Comment: Yeah, looks like! For example, I thought that since it is all about AST, that I could return like `~(expr)` from a function, and it will replace the caller as if being explicitly written here. But looks like that `~` works differently... Thanks for the `~'` -> `#` advice also! Now I have fixed all the macro and it works fine!